# Computer re-building, won't start

Tags: boot, hardware-failure

Okay I originally bought a Lenovo ThinkCentre computer, and now I have upgraded it so much that from the parts I am not currently using any more I could build a new one. I have put together all of the original parts for the lenovo computer but it won't start.
What happens it I hit the start button the fans start up the hard drive starts turning, some times you can hear the driver head start moving as well.

**Parts in use:**
**Mother board-** Lenovo, no other details
**Memory-** Samsung 4GBx2
**HDD -** an acer one (had to buy it, original is in use)
**Power Supply -** Huntkey 250w
**Graphics card -** None currently because I am just trying to get into BIOS, still has same problem when I install my AMD r7 250 of which has worked in the past.

**I have already tried:** Removing the clock battery and CMOS jumper then putting them on, Swapping around RAM including different RAM, tried a different PSU (no change).

Also no beep errors.

Comment: does it stay "on" or does it power off?

Comment: stays on for 3 to 2 seconds then turns off, but if I do not let it stay off with out power plugin for 30 seconds then it won't turn on at all.  Also when it dose turn on it dose not beep and does not out-put any display either.